# PHP Warning: gzinflate(): data error in

Tags: php, gzip

I pack my code using gzdeflate(), after I do addslashes() and write it to file like $var ='MY_RESULT';
After it I try to execute it using eval(stripslashes(gzinflate($var))) and get error Warning: gzinflate(): data error in this row. If I set $var = addslashes(gzdeflate("my_original_code")) everything work nice, but I need to put deflated result in this variable. So where is my mistake? Here is my code:

```
<?php
$source = file_get_contents("source.txt");
$gz = addslashes(gzdeflate($source,9));
$a = "<?php \$var='";
$b = "'; eval(gzinflate(stripslashes(\$var)));";
$result = $a.$gz.$b;

$fp = fopen('result.php', 'wb');
fwrite($fp, $result);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Apart from the missing semi-colon at the end of line 5 (`$b = "...;";`), a simplified version of that code with no write to file appears to work fine: http://3v4l.org/Uigv4

Comment: Yes, but I need working code with writing to file.

Comment: My point was that I could not reproduce your problem with the simplified example, and that that might help narrow down the problem. I'm trying to help you discover the problem, not write your code for you.

Comment: In fact, putting the file-writing back in still results in working code for me. Here is the code I ran: https://gist.github.com/IMSoP/368a6819b07458912b8a

Answer (score 2):

You need to reverse the order of encoding steps when you're decoding.

Encoding steps:

1. take the code, apply gzip compression, giving compressed code
2. take the compressed code, add slashes, giving escaped compressed code

Your current decoding steps:

1. take the escaped compressed code, and attempt to decompress it
2. take the result of (1) and attempt to remove slashes

Clearly that won't work. You need to:

1. take the escaped compressed code, remove slashes, giving compressed code
2. take the compressed code, decompress it, giving the original code

So in short, instead of `stripslashes(gzinflate($var))`, you need `gzinflate(stripslashes($var))`.

[Why on earth you're doing all this, and running `eval()` on the result, I dread to think, but there's your bug.]

Comment: Doesn't help, also get error. Added code to first message.

Answer (score 0):

lower gzdeflate compression level to less than 9, or add base64_encode before gzdeflate.